# how to pass parameter to a page?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, parameter-passing

I have a page that is loaded into a frame. in the code behind, i have a string variable called mode. What i want to do is when a hyperlink is clicked, open the page and set the mode

I was hoping to do it declaratively. I tried doing

```
NavigatUri="myPage?mode=edit"
```

and then adding the following to the code behind after the initialize component call

```
mode = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["mode"];
```

But I was getting a page not found error. I have a feeling I'm on another planet. I'm new to silverlight. How do i navigate to a page in this fashion and pass that argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `UriMapper` in you main page.  The final `UriMapping` would normally be the catch all that looks like this:-

```
<uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml"/>
```

You will note the "/" at the beginning of the Uri and the corresponding page belongs in the "/Views" folder.

Use the attribute:-

```
 NavigatUri="/myPage?mode=edit"
```

make sure your page in the Views folder.

However I'm pretty sure you already have that.  Your real problem is your attempt to access the `NavigationContext` in the execution the page constructor.  Its not available at that point in the pages lifecycle.  You should not attempt to use it until `OnNavigatedTo` is executed.

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    public MyPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        string mode = null;
        if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("mode"))
        {
            mode = NavigationContext.QueryString["mode"];
        }

        // Do stuff with mode.
    }
}
```

The reason you are seeing "page not found error" is thats because the Nav apps `ErrorWindow` just assumes any failure to load a page was because it wasn't found.  Which assuming you've coded your pages correctly is probably a reasonable assumption.

Comment: im using one of the templates, I can't find where the uri mapper is lol. It should be set up just like this though. I tried this and it's not seeming to work. I'm not getting the error anymore, but its not receiving the parameter

Comment: found the uri mapper, it is set up as described but still not working with the parameter. I changed the the mode value to formMode. I ran a display to show what keys were present in the navigation context and it is showing there is a key called mode, but i cant seem to do modify it, and the formMode is not getting passed.

Comment: actually, i just noticed that in the address bar, ?mode=2 is being passed despite the fact that my hyperlink control says ?formMode=edit

Comment: figured it out lol.... i was just on the completely wrong page. I got mixed up with what page was actually causing the redirect... fail on my part. Solution works fine lol thanks